# Topological terms VEVs and ghosts

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry-breaking, topology, instantons, non-perturbative

Suppose we have the Standard model, and we want to calculate with VEVs of topological susceptibilities of $SU_{L}(2), U_{Y}(1)$ and $SU_{c}(3)$ fields, which have the form
$$
\tag 1 \kappa \equiv \lim_{p \to 0} p_{\mu}p_{\nu}\int d^{4}xe^{ipx} \langle \text{vac}|T\left( K^{\mu}(x)K^{\nu}(0)\right) |\text{vac}\rangle \equiv \lim_{p \to 0}p_{\mu}p_{\nu}\Pi^{\mu \nu}(p)
$$
In principle, there exist topological configurations for all of groups (we need to take into an accounts that instanton configurations are forbidden for electroweak sector, but there are exist instanton-like configurations for which an action is finite), however, existence of nonzero VEV is more complicated question.

From the other way, existence of nonzero topological susceptibility implies the **pole structure** of $\Pi^{\mu \nu}$: for being nonzero, the $\Pi^{\mu \nu}$ in rhs has to be
$$
\lim_{p \to 0}\Pi^{\mu \nu}(p) = A\frac{g^{\mu \nu}}{p^{2}} + B\frac{p^{\mu}p^{\nu}}{p^{4}},
$$
i.e., there must be the ghost state which couples to gauge variant Chern-Simons form $K^{\mu}$.

The situation is known in pure QCD, for which 
$$
\lim_{p \to 0}p_{\mu}p_{\nu}\Pi^{\mu \nu}(p) \sim -\langle| \bar{\tilde{u}}\tilde{u} |\rangle \neq 0
$$
in the broken phase. This can be undestood as the fact that the gluons are confined in the broken phase.

What to do in the case of $SU_{L}(2)\times U_{Y}(1)$ group? How to calculate topological susceptibilities?

Comment: How is this different from [this old question of yours](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/222874/50583)?

Comment: @ACuriousMind : now I relate nonzero value of topological susceptibility to the presence of the ghost.